# Netbeans debugger for QT not stopping at breakpoints

Tags: qt, debugging, netbeans, breakpoints

I have Netbeans 8.2, Linux operating system, QT 4.8. I am remotely working on a QT application. I can run the application from Netbeans, but the debugger does not stop at the breakpoints, nor do those breakpoints show up in the window. I know this is not a remote issue, as I can debug a project that is not QT. Any suggestions?

Comment: Remotely? Is gdbserver involed and gdb configured to work with it? Not Qt issue for sure.

Comment: I do not think that the gdbserver is involved. But, I can debug a regular file fine on Netbeans remotely. I will  try a gdbserver

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem. I put CONFIG += qt debug_and_release_target instead of CONFIG += qt debug in my .pro file, ran qmake again and now the debugger works.